# Test/Automate table contents where case-insensitive sort is the only requirement, but that column has same-word different-case items

Tags: c#, sorting, selenium, datatable

I need a way to test and verify that my UI table contents are populated with the correct items from the database and sorted correctly. Currently, I have a query that returns the data that I need (sorted case insensitively on one of the columns) from the DB and then places that query result into type DataTable. I then have a method in C#/Selenium that converts the UI's table contents into type DataTable. I want to do an Assert AreEqual or a custom assert on these 2 datatables to make sure they match.

But I am running into problems because the table that needs to be verified is sorted on a column that contains a bunch of same-word different-case items, and the requirements for said table specifies that this column should be sorted case insensitively.

So everytime I load the page, those same-word different-case items are sometimes at different indexes in the list/table. For example, I can load the page the first time and see:

```
NETWORK  COLUMNTHATISSORTED
Net1     word 1    
Net2     WORD 2
Net3     word 2
Net4     WORD 2
Net5     word 3
```

I can load the page a second time and see this:

```
NETWORK  COLUMNTHATISSORTED
Net1     word 1    
Net3     word 2
Net4     WORD 2
Net2     WORD 2
Net5     word 3
```

Based on the requirements, this is perfectly fine and not considered a defect. But for automation testing purposes, I cant think of a way to code for this. If I use a simple AreEqual Assert, the inconsistency of the same-word different-case items fails the test sometimes. How do I get around this with C# or Selenium code?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the UI datatable before assertion, like:

```
datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "NETWORK";
datatable = datatable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: This would verify that the table has the correct contents, however, it doesn't satisfy the test criteria that says to test that the UI Table's Case Insensitive sort is working.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the second table is the correct output?
I would then break COLUMNTHATISSORTED into 2 columns (col1, col2), and then sort as `datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "col2, col1"`

Comment: Both tables are the 'correct' output. That is the problem. There is no pattern or rule that the same-word different-case items are following, because the requirement is a plain-jane case insensitive sort. So I have to come up with a way to verify that the entire table is sorted case insensitively. Cant figure it out because the same-word different-case item groups are randomly indexed every time

Comment: I can't use a DataTable sort method, as this would NOT test that the UI table is sorting correctly. Because I am sorting after the fact myself

Comment: What is your expected data?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean to "verify that my UI table contents are populated with the correct items from the database and sorted correctly.", you should know what your expectation is. You showed 2 tables of data from your UI - which I understand is your actual result. But maybe you can show what you expect too. Because with assertion, you need 2 tables of data to compare with each other.

Comment: They are both expected. The same-word different-case items are expected to be indexed randomly, there is no pattern. So I need a way to verify that the non-same-word items are sorted case insensitively while at the same time verifying that the same-word items are grouped together in that sort, regardless of how they are sorted within their group

Comment: I think you can try to convert the entire  column to lowercase?